# Load single array element into a display div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

I have a navigation div which contains an array of $deals (which are hyperlinks).  Each deal is displayed in the div with the following lines.

```
echo '<div id="productMenuBar" . class="productMenuBar">';
foreach ($deals as $k => $v)
{
    echo "<a href='#{$k}'>{$k}</a>" . ", "; 
}
echo '</div>';
```

So $k is a hyperlink to the mainwrapper container which has a heading (nike, addidas, puma etc) and smaller div boxes containing 1 or more actual product deals.

```
foreach ($deals as $k => $v)
{
    echo '<div id="mainwrapper">';
    echo '<a id="'.$k.'">' . '<h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($k))).' ' . 'Promotion'.'</h2>';

    foreach ($v as $key => $val)
    {
        if ($val['id'] =="02")  //01 for horizontal  02 for vertical
        {
            echo "<div id=\"wrapper1\"><img class=\"deallogo\" src=\"".$val['logo']."\"><div class=\"dealstitle\">".$val['productTitle']."</div>";
            echo "<div class=\"vcontainer\"><img class=\"vertical-img\" src=\"".$val['productImage']."\"><div class=\"vdescription\">".$val['productDescription']."</div><div class=\"vpricing\"><div class=\"vrrp\">".$val['rrp']."<div class=\"vsalesprice\">".$val['salePrice']."</div></div></div></div></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div id=\"lwrapper1\"><img class=\"deallogo\" src=\"".$val['logo']."\"><div class=\"dealstitle\">".$val['productTitle']."</div>";
            echo "<div class=\"dealscontainer\"><img class=\"horizontal-img\" src=\"".$val['productImage']."\"><div class=\"dealsdescription\">".$val['productDescription']."</div><div class=\"dealspricing\"><div class=\"rrp\">".$val['rrp']."</div><div class=\"salesprice\">".$val['salePrice']."</div></div></div></div>";
        }
     }

    echo "</div>";      
}
```

The deals themselves are getting pulled from a multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$deals = array (
        "nike" => array (
                        array( all deal 1 info in here),
                        array( all deal 2 info in here),
                        array( all deal 3 info in here)),
        "puma" = array(
                        array( all deal 1 info in here),
                        array( all deal 2 info in here),
                        array( all deal 3 info in here)),
        "addidas" = array(
                        array( all deal 1 info in here),
                        array( all deal 2 info in here),
                        array( all deal 3 info in here)),
);
```

The problem is that the array is getting bigger and bigger and they are all getting displayed on the one page.  This means when you click on a link in the navigation div, it can jump way down the page to the target deal.  What I would like to do instead is load the specific deal (for example only the nike, or only the puma, or only the addidas) after clicking the brand name in the navigation div and load only those deals from the array into the mainwrapper div.  I am assuming this will involve a bit of javascript, and some sort of onClick behaviour but I don't know where to start??  Unfortunately I unable to use JQuery for internal reasons!!

Any help much appreciated.

Volterony

Comment: Where is your markup? What are you doing in the front-end with JS? What have you tried?

Comment: I've not done anything with js. Currently all the deals are getting displayed on one page and the formatting is done with css.  That is why I am asking for help as I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: Any chance you can set up a mockup in a fiddle for us to take a look at?

Comment: I am using PHP with this so not sure if I can use php with jsfiddle?